# Deploying jhipster app to a different context path

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jhipster

I am trying to deploy a jhipster app using 'mvn' command. I believe this will run the default spring-boot:run. I think this deploys to tomcat. Once the server start's the application is availabe at http://localhost:8080. This works fine. But, i want to set a context path to the application, i don't want to deploy it to the root.

For example: http://localhost:8080/test should take me to the application index page.

I tired the following, but it did not work.

mvn -Pprod package

java -jar target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war -Dserver.contextPath=/test

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After few hours of googling and trying different things, I can vouch for the effectiveness of setting the property in `application-local.yml` for me.

So in my `application-local.yml` file, I set:

```
server:
     port: 8080
     contextPath: /test
```

Spring Boot comes with some pre-built property support, which can be defined in `application.properties` file.