# context path for java services deployment in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Where to set context path for java services?

I tried contexpath for application-prod.yml as given in [Deploying jhipster app to a different context path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064885/deploying-jhipster-app-to-a-different-context-path), but did not work.

Only the context path for rest api after changing is still /api and not /test

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So you changed application-prod.yml but did you run your app with prod profile?

Comment: When I copy my application-prod.yml : stackoverflow stated me that it is a spam and hence removed the same. Yes able to run app and able to call services from /api/get... and not /test/get.. or /test/api/get...